# Preventing water from entering carport

Tags: water, carport

How can I prevent water from entering my carport? My entire front yard and driveway slope toward my house. Negative draining issue. I have french (or trench) drains installed across the entire width of the front of my house. However, I don't have anything preventing the water running down the driveway from entering my carport. If I could just redirect it, I think the water would bypass my carport and head down my backyard if there were something to redirect it. I'm attaching a picture to show you. There is a drain on the left side of my carport (if you're facing the carport). One option might be to install another similar drain across the entire width of my driveway right before the carport entrance and then connect that drain to the existing drain. OR, is there a less invasive and less expensive option that would work? I've been considering whether a burm (sp?) or speed bump would solve the problem. Any ideas? I can't figure out how to add a picture...

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. If you edit the URL of your pictures into your question, someone will be along to edit the pictures in.

Answer (score 2):

Most people in your situation trench the driveway, drain it off somewhere, and put a grate on it.

The speed bump could work if it was big enough, but chances are (1) some water would come over it, and (2) you'd probably hate it enough that you trench in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You might try a drain channel in front of the door, pulling any water to the side and into you french drain lines.  Easier to cut one of these in then redoing the entire driveway. Here's an example on

> [Amazon. Drainage Trench & Driveway Channel Drain](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B006YVE71W)

Many other options are available, different widths, plastic grates, ect...Just shop around a little.